# php malware shows in grep but not in file

Tags: php, wordpress, vim, grep, malware

Is there a known way to hide PHP code within a file?

I got an error message referencing a malware variable in a php file on a wordpress website.

- When I grep for the variable it shows me the malware in the file
- When I open the file in nano it doesn't show
- When I download via sftp the malware doesn't show in notepad++

I'm wondering if:

- grep could somehow be seeing 'cached files'?
- is there is a way to hide php code?
- has anyone using php or wordpress ever seen something like this?

I did everything to double check, yes these are the same files and all the other tips that were pointed out. opcache is off. I have no idea.

Comment: strange...are you sure you have the same file? maybe grep found the file in a backup folder? maybe the malware code is hidden after long lines of whitespace? sorry, no real clue, just throwing out ideas

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not reasonably answerable with the information you've provided.

Comment: Yeah, thanks everyone. My real question was, has anyone seen or experienced this problem. I wasn't able to find anything (hard to even build the query) on google, which is why I posted. It seems like the answer is "no". I take everyone's advice to rule out user-error face-palms and have enlisted sysadmins to help, they are equally baffled.

Answer (score 1):

Removing face palming situations from the equation (e.g. downloading the wrong file, downloading from the different server - which have happened to me before ;)), maybe you could try to use

`grep -n [variable name]`

to figure out the line (-n) where the variable is in the file. That might help you.

Another suggestion is downloading the file and using diff tools against a known good version of the infected file.